# Is this a transitive dependency?

Tags: sql, database, functional-dependencies, transitive-dependency

I have this simplified table:

[image]

The business states that anyone with a `role_id` of `3` needs to have a `leader_id`, while anyone with any other value for `role_id` should not have a `leader_id` (`null`).

By knowing the value of `leader_id` we now narrow down the possible values for `role_id`. Have I unwillingly created a transitive dependency between `leader_id` and `role_id`?

Comment: Does a `leader_id` value _uniquely_ determine the value for `role_id` ?

Comment: Any value other than `null` in the `leader_id` column would require the `role_id` column to be `3`.

Comment: I see a problem with mapping `leader_id` to `role_id`.  We can't have `NULL` mapping to both `1` and `2`.  Maybe you should be mapping `role_id` to `leader_id` instead?

Comment: This feels more like a constraint than anything to do with dependencies

Comment: This is a business constraint, not an actual DB dependency, yes.

Comment: What *reference* for normalization are you using? What are *definitions* of "FD" & "partial FD"? *When* (ie in what *other definition*) are partial FDs problematic? Also, your question cannot be answered until you determine all the FDs (functional dependencies) of the table. "By knowing the value" is just too sloppy to be of use. Also: Normalization theory does not deal with NULL. If no nullable column is part of a non-trivial FD's determinant then you can normalize as usual. Otherwise you must convert to such a design, normalize, then denormalize.

Comment: There is no difference between "a business constraint" and "an actual DB dependency". (Tables state how the business situation is, so saying that the table values are limited is the same as saying that the business situations are limited.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not a transitive-dependency : the role alone doesn't provide you with enough information to find the leader; also, the leader alone doesn't provide enough information to find the role (for null values).

A transitive-dependency means that you must be able to discover a value X from another value Y with a perfect score.

For exemple, if you know the *City*, you obviously know the *Country* as well, you don't have to create two columns (city and country), you only need the city, and by using the transitive-dependency, you will get the country.